# Populate db values fill dynamically in textbox, based on selection of dropdown in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have used two fields in my DB, one field name is the category and another field name is mobile. I have already done it to Displaying category values in drop down box. but I just need to select those category value from drop-down selection then I want to show its mobile number in textbox field. any help greatly appreciated.

**Dropdown box code:-**

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
  <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>">
      <?php echo $row1[4];?>
    </option>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

**Input box code:-**

```
<input placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" id="pnum"  type="text">
```

**Javascript/AJAX POST:-**

```
$('#cat').click(function() {
  var package = $('#cat').val();
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      'package': package
    }, //Have u tried this
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax1.php',
    //dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#pnum').val(data);
    }
  });
});
```

**ajax1.php:-**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['package'])) {
    $query = "select * from `user_content` where Category=" . $_POST['package'];
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo $res['Mobile'];
        }   
    }
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the Payload of your request?

Comment: It should be `isset($_POST['package'])`. Remove the explanation mark.

Comment: The line `if(!isset($_POST['pakcage'])) {` shouldn't be negated (have the `!` before it), as with the `!` you are saying if the index "package" doesn't exist then try and access it, whereas you want to only access it if it does exists

Comment: thanks, I removed this explanation mark. but indexing error comes again

Comment: Close that `<select name="cat" id="cat" ` ???. And it's "exclamation mark"!

Comment: @kerbholz yeah i did it

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I noticed wrong in your code is semi-colon `;` after `while` loop.

So change following:

```
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
```

with:

```
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):?>
```

The problem of undefined index is due to use of wrong condition here:

```
if (!isset($_POST['package']))
```

This should look like:

```
if (isset($_POST['package']))
```

Comment: yeah thanks for your reply now I change this.. but Undefined index error cannot be resolved

Comment: hai @Lovepreet Singh i change this if (isset($_POST['package'])) code as per your instruction, now when i running this php page (ajax1.php) it will not show any error .. I am already Displaying and fetch category values in the drop down. I want to select those category value from dropdown then I want to show its mobile number in textbox field. I am working on this but not succeeded. please help me.